# Pipeline with JedisCluster unsupported

Tags: java, spring, redis, jedis, spring-data-redis

I'm writing a web application in Spring, and am using Spring Data Redis with Jedis. The web app talks to a redis cluster with a lot of set commands"
I'd like to send commands to the redis cluster in a pipeline. When I tried that I got an exception:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Pipeline is currently not
>   supported for JedisClusterConnection.

What would be my alternative?

Edit1:

```
protected void store(Map<String,Creative> creativesToStore, Function<Map<String,Creative>,Object> executedAction)
{
    this.redisTemplate.execute(
            redisConnection -> executedAction.apply(creativesToStore), true, true); // Pipelined execution*/

}

protected Object storeAllCreativesRedis(Map<String,Creative> creativesToStore)
{
    creativesToStore.keySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(key -> creativesToStore.get(key)!=null)
            .forEach(key -> {
                redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(key, creativesToStore.get(key), ttlSeconds, timeUnit);
                logger.debug("Issuing a redis set for %s ",key);
            });
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Share your code, not just the exception?

Comment: You can connect to the node your keys are located and use pipelining directly.

Comment: Can you show an example of how to connect to an individual node in a cluster please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a [Redisson](https://redisson.org) framework? It supports Redis pipeline in cluster mode. Below is the example:

```
RBatch batch = redisson.createBatch(BatchOptions.defaults());
batch.getMap("test1").fastPutAsync("1", "2");
batch.getMap("test2").fastPutAsync("2", "3");
batch.getMap("test3").putAsync("2", "5");
batch.getAtomicLong("counter").incrementAndGetAsync();
batch.getAtomicLong("counter").incrementAndGetAsync();
batch.execute();
```